# Inherited interface hides parent in Orchard framework

Tags: orchardcms, autofac

I created an interface `ISecureStorageProvider` like below.

```
public interface ISecureStorageProvider : IStorageProvider
{
}
```

Concrete implementation for `ISecureStorageProvider` looks like below.

```
public class SecureAzureBlobStorageProvider : AzureFileSystem, ISecureStorageProvider 
{
}
```

What I found was, the class `SecureAzureBlobStorageProvider` gets injected for both the interfaces `ISecureStorageProvider` , `IStorageProvider`. But, I want both of them to be available, not one suppressing another.